# Sessions aren't automatically removing themselves from Database?

Tags: database, zend-framework, session

I'm playing around with keeping sessions in the database and I'm new to this. The method in ZF makes it create id's in the database beautifully, however I don't see the database deleting any sessions once they're made, even though I'm setting the lifetime to 20 seconds.

Is the database supposed to delete them itself, or is it up to me? or is it a setup I must do? Thank you!

Comment: The database will not delete them automatically (it has no notion of a "timeout" or how to process it). The framework itself should work twofold: 1) It should *not accept* an expired session, even if there is a database entry 2) It should provide a mechanism for *periodically purging* session information from the database. Hopefully these are covered in the ZF documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like the `destroy()` method of `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_dbTable` might be what you're looking for assuming you're using `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_dbTable` to save your sessions.

Here is the method definition:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $return = false;

        if ($this->delete($this->_getPrimary($id, self::PRIMARY_TYPE_WHERECLAUSE))) {
            $return = true;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```